# What css element to select for Nationality of a player while scraping SoFifa.com using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

So I've been trying to scrape SoFifa.com for player details using the rvest package. Went the extra mile to scrape column by column from the table. Here is where I get stuck. I cant get the Player Nationality. Maybe I'm selecting the wrong CSS element. Tried using the selector gadget tool and still no luck. Following is the code. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
#Website link to be scraped with selected columns.

link= "https://sofifa.com/"


#Name of each player. This works perfectly fine as all names are retrived

Name <- link %>% read_html() %>% 
        html_nodes(".nowrap") %>% 
        html_text() 


#Nationality is not displayed. While inspecting this section, I observed that title of the element < a rel=nofollow> under <div class="bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis">
needs to be selected. Need help to how to do that!!

Nationality <- link %>% read_html() %>% 
        html_nodes(".flag") %>% 
        html_text() 

#Tried .flag as the selector gadget suggested it but still it doesnt retrieve the Nationality for a player
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can combine two attributes to get what you are after . 
Try :

```
#<a rel="nofollow" href="/players?na=14" title="England">...</a>
# the *= in css selectors means that attribute contains a certain text
# here is the css selecot     
#.bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis a[rel="nofollow"][href*="players?"]

page <- read_html(link)
Nationality  <- page %>% html_nodes('.bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis a[rel="nofollow"][href*="players?"]') %>% html_attr('title')
print(Nationality )
```

Output:

```
[1] "Italy"          "England"        "Togo"           "France"
 [5] "Ghana"          "Brazil"         "Norway"         "Spain"
 [9] "Nigeria"        "Argentina"      "Spain"          "England"
[13] "Portugal"       "England"        "Denmark"        "England"
[17] "Italy"          "Argentina"      "England"        "Portugal"
[21] "Argentina"      "Norway"         "Brazil"         "Norway"
[25] "Netherlands"    "Germany"        "England"        "Uruguay"
[29] "United States"  "Argentina"      "Netherlands"    "Czech Republic"
[33] "Brazil"         "France"         "Argentina"      "Brazil"
[37] "Poland"         "Brazil"         "Italy"          "Portugal"
[41] "Netherlands"    "Netherlands"    "Netherlands"    "Morocco"
[45] "Argentina"      "Spain"          "Argentina"      "France"
[49] "Netherlands"    "Brazil"         "Argentina"      "France"
[53] "Canada"         "Canada"         "Switzerland"    "Brazil"
[57] "Germany"        "Netherlands"    "Jamaica"        "France"
```

Comment: you just beat me to it :-). I was having issues with the `href`. Can you tell me why it needs to be `*=`?

Comment: @ahmed.soli Okay, I get it that the title attribute needs to extracted. Can you please help me out with the code?

 
Nationality <- link %>% read_html() %>% 
                    html_nodes(".bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis")  %>% 
                    html_attr(a[rel="nofollow"][href*="players?"])   
                })
Not 100% sure about this. Please correct me, I know its wrong!!

Comment: @ahmed.soli Perfect!!